# InnoDB Tablespace Encryption available with MySQL v5.6?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Can InnoDB Tablespace Encryption be used with MySQL version 5.6? Or is this plugin feature only for version 5.7 and up?

Was there a similar plugin/functionality in MySQL version 5.6 that allowed encryption of tables and/or databases?

Comment: dup of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194438/is-there-a-table-data-at-rest-solution-for-mysql-v5-6

Comment: you cannot possible to innodb-tablespace-encryption in MySQL 5.6 , switch to 5.7 and user AES encryption use https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-tablespace-encryption.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any patch or plugin to implement tablespace encryption on MySQL 5.6.

- MariaDB 10.1 includes a patch for tablespace encryption, based on an open-source patch released by Google.

  Encryption is optional for the InnoDB redo log.

  Not supporting encryption: query logs, error logs, audit logs,
  metadata in `.frm` files.

  Binary logs are encrypted, but mysqlbinlog cannot read them 
  unless reading from a remote server. Percona XtraBackup cannot 
  read encrypted MariaDB tablespaces or logs.
- MySQL 5.7.11 and Percona Server 5.7.11 implement tablespace
  encryption. Only file-per-table tablespaces are encrypted.

  Not supporting encryption: InnoDB redo logs, binary logs,
  system tablespace, general tablespaces, and undo logs.
- MySQL 8.0 improves encryption a bit more, allowing InnoDB redo logs and undo logs to be encrypted.

If you really need full encryption for all sensitive data at rest, you should look into filesystem-level encryption. Filesystem encryption should work no matter what version of MySQL you use.

Answer (score 0):

No, mysql v5.6 does not support the InnoDB tablespace encryption feature. You could have easily verified this yourself by checking the syntax of `create table` in the mysql documentation. The v5.6 documentation does not include the `encryption` option.

Recommending any plugins is explicitly off-topic on SO, therefore I will not discuss your 2nd question.